# Should i use return on mongo error

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

On my node.js app, if an error occurs on a mongo query i use res.end. But will the code keep executing, and should i put a return after res.end?

```
book.find({key:'123'},function(err){
   if(err) res.end();
   console.log("lots of blah blah");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To stop the "blah blah" you should `return res.end();`.

Something like:

```
book.find({key:'123'},function(err){
   if(err) return res.end();
   console.log("lots of blah blah");
});
```